# Is MySQL smart enough to not do a full table scan for LIKE or NOT LIKE when there are other conditions?

Tags: mysql

I know that full wildcard searches (example: `LIKE '%word%'`) cause a full table scan.

Is MySQL smart enough to only scan the results, not the entire table, when I use LIKE or NOT LIKE?

For example, say I have a query that selects 10 rows out of 1000000. The query is something like `select * from table where id <= 10 and description NOT LIKE '%word%'`. Is MySQL smart enough to only scan those 10 result rows?

(My query is very different but that's the gist of it: I want to use NOT LIKE on a result set from a large table. Assume everything is indexed. Client version "14.14 Distrib 5.7.29, for Linux (x86_64)", server version "5.7.29-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 for Linux on x86_64".)

Comment: If you have an index on id in your example, that index will probably be used.

Comment: Yes, sorry-- assume indexes on everything. (I know that `LIKE '%word%'` ignores indexes, though.)

Comment: It is **CRITICAL** that you provide your version of MySQL! p.s. welcome to the forum! Anyway, can't you run the query using `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` and see?

Comment: I added the version. It is client version "14.14 Distrib 5.7.29, for Linux (x86_64)", server version "5.7.29-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 for Linux on x86_64".

Comment: No - I was quite clear. It's your version of **MySQL** that we need and **not** your version of Linux!

Comment: _"..assume indexes on everything.."_ If you mean an index for each column that isn't enough. Queries that restricts the result set by multiple conditions on multiple columns need an multicolumn index.

Comment: @Vérace, I answered you. The fact that I included the full version string (that includes Linux) is not a valid complaint. It is the output of `mysql --version` and `mysqld --version`.

Comment: My apologies (hangs head like puppy expecting to be slapped...) - it's just that it looked like the output of `uname -a`  or similar. I was just expecting 5.7 (or 5.6 or 8)... ah well, better luck next time! As for your question, have you run `EXPLAIN EXTENDED <your query>` to see if MySQL is smart enough to use the index on `id`?

Answer (score 1):

Given `NOT LIKE '%...'` cannot use an index and `id` can, provided a index (include primary key) begins with `id`, then it will be used.

`EXPLAIN [EXTENDED] {query}` will show what indexes the query planner plans to use for the query.